# Google Sheets Formula for Attendance Records

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a very overwhelming and large attendance sheet of 350+ people that I need to keep track of. I have a very simple attendance record of 0 if you weren't there and 1 if you were. For one of our events, in particular, people sign in through a Google sheet document. I would like to be able to take the names of the people that I have in one sheet and add a 0 or 1 to the "main" attendance sheet if their name appears on the sign-up sheet. Is there a formula that I could use to do this?

I have created a "mock" attendance record of something similar to what I need. Here are the images:

[image: Main "Official Attendance" Sheet]

But notice how I have a separate sheet entitled 2/21 General Meeting of all the people who attended that specific event.

[image: Secondary "2/21 General Meeting" Sheet]

So for the "Official Attendance" sheet, I would like to add a 1 next to Bob Smith, etc5, etc11, etc2, and etc12 and a 0 to everyone else in the 2/21 General Meeting column.

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L35VDU5YTyTJNIHJ4uOX6yX4ACF8uF9aSU83LHo_a-M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That is the copy of the actual sheet, minus a few minor details.  I forgot I could make a copy of something! Hopefully that's easier to view.

Comment: row 146 needs to be cleared

Comment: Just posted a concise solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A6:A), 
 IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A6:A, '1/17 Callout Meeting'!C1:C, 1, 0), )<>"", 1, 0), ))
```

[image]

Comment: So maybe I'm doing something wrong, but it returns "0" for everyone for me. I added the function to the sheet if you want to view it.

Comment: That was my fault for changing the 1/17 Callout Meeting sheet! I figured it out.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: np, if thats all pls mark the answer as solved

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you can use.
One such option: Use in D2 the following formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SIGN(IFERROR(MATCH(A2:A,'2/21 General Meeting'!A$2:A,0),0)))
```